# Align images using table

Tags: html, css

How would I go about aligning four images (two square images and two rectangular images) using a table? Should look something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRIxu.jpg

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/B8jHVoB.png" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SXEsKuc.png" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SXEsKuc.png" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/B8jHVoB.png" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example or image of what it's supposed to look like? Your description of the "two rectangular images overlapping vertically" is hard to visualize, especially since table cells aren't meant to overlap.

Comment: Tables are for tabular data, not layout. Use CSS.

Comment: CSS is over 20 years old. Stop using tables for layout.

Comment: @JonUleis updated

Comment: And here is just example how it could be done with nested tables: https://jsfiddle.net/cz142y29/ O, memories.... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't make much sense to use a table for what you want does it? A table has equal size cells in an entire column - which is exactly what you don't want. One CSS solution:

```html
   <div style="white-space:nowrap;">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/B8jHVoB.png" />
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SXEsKuc.png" />
   </div>
   <div style="white-space:nowrap;">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SXEsKuc.png" />
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/B8jHVoB.png" />
   </div>
```

Almost forgot: don't use an inline style, set a class to hold a row of images, with the white-space: no-wrap as an attribute.

Comment: Thank you for actually being helpful